# How to split array with objects by key-values in it

Tags: javascript, arrays

JavaScript. Have an array of objects

```
0:{mask: "202 203, 287 376, 412 162, 381 121", add: 1}
1:{mask: "108 511, 247 291, 151 186, 97 180", add: 1}
2:{mask: "147 202, 289 234, 268 113", add: 0}
3:{mask: "79 225, 318 374, 443 212, 359 118", add: 1}
4:{mask: "116 253, 327 351, 377 198, 361 171", add: 1}
5:{mask: "232 237, 288 566, 406 481, 458 240, 421 188", add: 0}
6:{mask: "222 391, 361 298, 347 170", add: 0}
```

Need to split they to arrays with `add = 1` and few `add = 0` after, before next `add = 1`, with preservation of order like this

```
ar1 = [
  0: {mask: "202 203, 287 376, 412 162, 381 121", add: 1}
]
ar2 = [
  0: {mask: "108 511, 247 291, 151 186, 97 180", add: 1}
  1: {mask: "147 202, 289 234, 268 113", add: 0}
]
ar3 = [
  0: {mask: "79 225, 318 374, 443 212, 359 118", add: 1}
]
ar4 = [
  0: {mask: "116 253, 327 351, 377 198, 361 171", add: 1}
  1: {mask: "232 237, 288 566, 406 481, 458 240, 421 188", add: 0}
  2: {mask: "222 391, 361 298, 347 170", add: 0}
]
```

it can be array of objects (with array inside) doesn't matter, the main thing is group element with `add = 1` with all next elements, that have `add = 0`

Comment: i recommend you to use the _ chunk method in lodash https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#chunk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reduce can help you although it's a trick. Your can adopt a for loop if you don't like reduce

```js
const arr = [{mask: "202 203, 287 376, 412 162, 381 121", add: 1},
{mask: "108 511, 247 291, 151 186, 97 180", add: 1},
{mask: "147 202, 289 234, 268 113", add: 0},
{mask: "79 225, 318 374, 443 212, 359 118", add: 1},
{mask: "116 253, 327 351, 377 198, 361 171", add: 1},
{mask: "232 237, 288 566, 406 481, 458 240, 421 188", add: 0},
{mask: "222 391, 361 298, 347 170", add: 0}];

const result = [];

arr.reduce((a,b) => {
  if (a === null || b.add == 1)
    result.push([]);
  result[result.length-1].push(b);
  
  return b
},null)

console.log(result);
```